# h2 in memory database spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I started a new spring-boot.Added some starters
jpa, web, h2.
in src/main/resources application.properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:navin
```

[image: screenshot of h2 database showing error]

When I try to connect shows this error please help

Comment: Currently, you are trying to connect to a file-based DB `~/test`. Use the correct JDBC URL in the H2-Console as defined in the properties: `jdbc:h2:mem:navin`

Comment: Thank you very much i wasted 3 hrs, now it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error the console is showing is: `Database "C/Users/aadit/test" not found`.

In the H2 Console under `JDBC URL` you should be using the url you defined in your `application.properties`: `jdbc:h2:mem:navin`